# Vlookup /indexmatch multiple rows based on a certain criteria

Tags: excel, vlookup

We are using SPSS to create regression models for a certain product. We have 3 models per product. The output we get from SPSS we are feeding into an excel sheet. In our sheet we have two fields, predictors and coefficients that are 5 columns each

The output that we get from SPSS looks like this:[image]

We need to move this data into this format:
[image]

How can I do this using formulas/vlookup etc. to do this. The challenge for me is that certain models have either 2 predictors like product D model 1 while some have 4 predictors like Product F model 1

Thank you.
Shyam

Comment: Can you please tell on how to identify values corresponds to predictor1, predictor2..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### step 1. Create name from selection

Select A1:D14 then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> and check top

---

### step 2. Write array formula for indep. variables

Select C18:G18 then write

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Predictor,TRANSPOSE(LARGE(IF((Product=$A18)*(Model=$B18),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS(Product))),""),ROW(INDIRECT("1:5"))))),"")
```

then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>

---

### step 3. Write array formula for coeff.

Select H18:L18 then write

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Coeff,TRANSPOSE(LARGE(IF((Product=$A18)*(Model=$B18),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS(Product))),""),ROW(INDIRECT("1:5"))))),"")
```

then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>

---

### step 4. Copy the array formulas and paste

Select C18:L18, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.
Select C19:C24, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: AWESOME! Thank you so much!!